# what will happen if service already fetch the job from the queue and then blow up

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, nservicebus

I'm new to this, please help me. I want to design a system with a web site and a service. The website accept user's request and put job into a queue. The service get job from queue and process it. But how to deal with the scenario that the service breaks down after it has already fetch the job from the queue? Is there a mechanism to know the system has crashed and put the job back to the queue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not familiar with `nservicebus`, but normally when you dequeue something from a robust message queue, it is hidden/unavailable to dequeue while the job is processing. When the job completes, the message can be permanently removed from the queue. After a specified timeout, the job is restored and available for dequeue again if it has not been marked as done, causing the job to be rerun if the thing that processed it has crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using MSMQ, by default messages are wrapped in a transaction when being put into the queues and when they are being processed (via a handler).

If the message was half way through the handler and power was cut to the server, the transaction would fail and the message would be left at the top of the queue. When the server came back up, the top message will be pulled off the queue and processed (the message that was being processed during the previous failure).